# How to include custom java script in adminhtml edit form?

Tags: magento2

I have created confirm password field in adminhtml edit.php file . For confirm password functionality, how to include java script in adminhtml edit form ?
Or 
other method to check confirm password in custom Module befor save the form ?

Comment: you have to create requirejs-config.js file and define your js inside it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to validate the password that it matches the entered password add validate-cpassword class to your validate password fiels. This is defined in lib/web/prototype/validation.js file so you may take a look if you want.

```
 $fieldset->addField(
            'password',
            'password',
            [
               'name' => 'password',
               'label' => __('New Password'),
               'title' => __('New Password'),
               'class' => 'validate-admin-password admin__control-text'
            ]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
           'confirmation',
           'password',
            [
               'name' => 'password_confirmation',
               'label' => __('Password Confirmation'),
               'class' => 'validate-cpassword admin__control-text'
           ]
      );
```

These line from magento core may help you

Answer (score 4):

You can set Custom.js file in your Layout file  xyz.xml only set head

```
<head>
    <script src="Test_Demo::js/custom.js"/>
</head>
```

also define this file name in 
view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            custom:'Test_Demo/js/custom'
        }
    }
};
```

=>finaly edit.php in use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(["jquery",custom], function ($) {
     alert(123);
});

=>Its working..
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You may include JS in admin form in following way:

> Create requirejs-config.js inside your module Path:
>
> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'jsalias':'Vendor_Module/js/jsalias'
        }
    }
};
```

> Create JS inside your module's adminhtml part
>
> Path:Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/jsalias.js
>
> Not it's time to include js inside your form.

```
$field = $fieldset->addField('password', 'password', array(
    'label' => 'password',
    'name' => 'password',
    'required' => true,
    'class' => 'required-entry input-text',
));
$field->setAfterElementHtml('<script>
//<![CDATA[
 
   require(["jquery","jsalias"], function ($) {
       alert('Yes.. It works..!!!');   
   });
 
//]]>
</script>');
```